# #REF in excel when using VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel

I keep getting #REF problem in Excel

all the numbers in red highlight are Currency (£)

Can anyone help me on this?

[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRHyI.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the VLOOKUP separate from the sum of the units

```
=VLOOKUP(B13,$A$1:$C$8,2,FALSE)*SUM(C13:I13)
```

Comment: @PatrykPierzgalski please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.